# Will `IBAction`/`IBOutlet` be accessible in the IB when they arent defined on the ViewController?

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I am new to Objective-C and iPhone development.

I have a collection class implementing common UI functionality, eg. an EditBox for typing a formula, a label where the result is rendered, and, a button for executing the calculation.

I want to be able to embed this functionality in various projects.
I don't want to generate the UI apriorialy, rather, I want to define a class with `IBOutlet` and `IBAction` elements, and, to be able to directly link them with whatever UI is implemented by the application (Using the Interface Builder).

Will `IBAction`/`IBOutlet` be accessible in the Interface Builder although they were implemented on a class different than the ViewController ?
Is this use-case possible with 'Objective-C' ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please don't instantiate non-UI/View elements in a XIB, it's poor form.

Comment: Yes you can, but ofcourse there is only one way to figure this out yourself: And that's trying :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes. you can instantiate every class in interface builder and then use that

e.g.
a Calculator class

=> drag a NSObject from the palette/library into the left pane of IB and change its class in the inspector to Calculator :) then you can use that